# Automatic retry on failure, How to set Backoff coefficient

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

```
const df = require("durable-functions");

module.exports = df.orchestrator(function*(context) {
    const retryOptions = new df.RetryOptions(5000, 3);

    yield context.df.callActivityWithRetry("FlakyFunction", retryOptions);

    // ...
});
```

[There are several options for customizing the automatic retry policy. They include the following:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-error-handling)

Max number of attempts: The maximum number of retry attempts.

First retry interval: The amount of time to wait before the first retry attempt.

Backoff coefficient: The coefficient used to determine rate of increase of backoff. Defaults to 1.

How to set Backoff coefficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of `RetryOptions` takes only two parameters, just set `backoffCoefficient` after construction, same as other parameters.

```
const retryOptions = new df.RetryOptions(5000, 3);
retryOptions.backoffCoefficient = 2;
```

Comment: Is this correct? In the Azure Python SDK and in the code of RetryOptions I only see it has the two attributes of the constructor and nothing else.